# sorting capped mongodb collection in spring boot

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-data-mongodb, capped-collections

I am trying to sort capped collection in descending order.

what I have tried:

```
    @Tailable
    @Query(sort = "{$natural:-1}")
    Flux<Message> findAllByConversationId(String conversationId);
```

it gives:

> Query failed with error code 2 and error message  cannot use tailable option with a sort other than {$natural: 1}'

but when I use this query in robo3t:

```
db.getCollection('message').find({}).sort({$natural:-1})
```

it works fine !

any help ?

Comment: please any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I needed to go with native queries using "ReactiveMongoTemplate"

this code works as I want:

```
public Flux<StreamMessageDto> streamConversationById(String conversationId) {
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("conversationId").is(conversationId);
    Query query = Query.query(criteria);
    query.with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "$natural"));
    reactiveMongoTemplate.find(query, Message.class);
}
```

for more details refer to [this](https://developpaper.com/mongodb-native-query-and-spring-data-mongodb-object/) link